# Sorting CSV Data in a Report

Tags: c#, csv, listlabel

I'm trying to print a CSV file with List & Label. I need to sort it by one of the columns, however the sort property is not available. If I use a SQL data source, I can sort it. How can I sort the CSV data? My source is

```
CsvDataProvider csvDta = new CsvDataProvider(@"C:\temp\myData.csv", true, "Data", ';');

using (ListLabel LL = new ListLabel() { DataSource = csvDta})
{
   LL.Design();
}
```

Comment: What is ListLabel?

Comment: The CsvDataProvider? is this from a nuget package?  it would seam that you need to define a class to represent your data row and put the output of your csv into a collection of this class.  then you would have access to linq extension methods

Comment: I edited the question to contain the suitable namespaces. It's one of the classes that ships with List & Label (a reporting package, see tag description for the tag listlabel)

Comment: My edit got rejected :( - don't know why. So I'm adding the namespaces to the answer below insted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be to wrap the CSV data in an InMemoryDataProvider. Try this:

```
using combit.ListLabel23;
using combit.ListLabel23.DataProviders;

CsvDataProvider csvDta = new CsvDataProvider(@"C:\temp\myData.csv", true, "Data", ';');

// wrap the table in a queryable data source
InMemoryDataProvider dataSource = new InMemoryDataProvider();
dataSource.AddTable(csvDta, "Data");

using (ListLabel LL = new ListLabel() { DataSource = dataSource})
{
   LL.Design();
}
```

This will give you all the glory of sorting and filtering you require.